# VBA Create filter for multiple columns

Tags: excel, vba, loops, filter

good night!

I'm new in VBA and my english isn't that good so, please, be patient with me =D

Since I'm new, I always did simple loops, with one column. I never had to do a filter before. So I confess I have no idea where to begin. But I'll try my best to explain, so please, help me because it's really important to me.

I need to create a loop in the first 5 columns with this logic:

1 - Search all 5 columns and create a filter;
2 - Filter: Get all rows of column A where value == 1 **And** all rows of column B where value == 1 **And** all rows of Column C where variable == 'C' **And** all rows of column D where values == 1 **And** all rows of column E where value == 1 and create another sheet(1) with all rows of the filter;
3 - Do loop 2 again, but with "J" on column "C", and create another sheet (2);

The logic is: I need to create one sheet with all the rows that I set in the filter.
Example: Find all rows on the Columns where Column A = 1 & Column B = 1 & Column C = F & Column D = 1 & Column E = 1 -> Create one sheet with all rows with this values

Just like that:

Note this: because I have Column C with "F" in a row and "J" in another row, I need to create one sheet with all rows that contains each letter.

[image]

Could you help me, please?

Thanks and have a great night!

Comment: You have two questions here which will lead to disqualification of your thread due to lack of focus. One, how to set a filter with several criteria. (Do it manually wile recording a macro. Then use then recorded code as a base for your question.) Two, how to copy the filtered result to a new sheet. Google this question and use the code you find as a base for your question.) I suggest you take these two steps and amend your question before it gets closed.

Comment: The VBA tag specifically states *"VBA is not equivalent to VB.NET"* and your question is on VBA so why have you tagged it VB.NET? Don't spam tags. It wastes the time of people you might want to help you.

Comment: Hi guys, good morning. I'm sorry, I'm new here, it was my 3rd post. I'll correct. Thanks!